# drag and drop of content from the googledocs pdf in the iframe is not working.

Tags: drag-and-drop

When I drag and drop the content of the pdf from the googledocs in the iframe is not working in any browser. I hope that as Google docs provides security so its not allowing drag and drop effect from the Google docs pdf. I'm not sure

How to drag the content from the google docs pdf?

Thanks in advance.